# How to generate a pem format privateKey with Java?

Tags: java, encryption, private-key, pem

I hava a `private key` is raw `byte[]` type, **need to be transform to a pem style**.

*So my question is*:

How to generate a pem format with Java?

Comment: what have you tried?  BouncyCastle?

Answer (score 1):

PEM format Keys are written to files in Base 64 encoding.

So, you will need to convert your bytes into that format and then save it.

---

Hope this helps!